# Кастомизация веб-форм битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Добрый день!

Возник следующий вопрос. Есть форма на битриксе, созданная через модуль феб форм. Все хорошо, ворма ресуется без проблем. Поля кастомизировал. Но не понятно одно:

*Нужно назначить css класс самой форме. По умолчанию класс самой форме не создается, в шаблоне компонента я не нашел самого тега <form, да и кривоватый подход мне кажется*

Может кто нибудь сталкивался с такой задачей...

Вот так в верстке

```
<form action="#" class="contact-form" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Вот так делает Bitrix

```
<form name="contact_form" action="/contacts/?bitrix_include_areas=Y&amp;clear_cache=Y" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Как добавить class="contact-form" к форме генерируемой битриксом

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле ведь всё очень просто.
В стандартном шаблоне вы можете видеть переменную `<?=$arResult["FORM_HEADER"]?>`, в которой содержится открывающий tag "form" и два скрытых служебных поля.

Открывающий tag можно написать вручную:

```
<form name="<?=$arResult["WEB_FORM_NAME"]?>" action="<?=POST_FORM_ACTION_URI?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-form" novalidate="novalidate">
```

Скрытое поле, содержащее ID формы:

```
<input type="hidden" name="WEB_FORM_ID" value="<?=$arParams["WEB_FORM_ID"]?>">
```

И скрытое поле, содержащее ID сессии:

```
<?=bitrix_sessid_post()?>
```

В итоге нужно строку  заменить на конструкцию:

```
<form name="<?=$arResult["WEB_FORM_NAME"]?>" action="<?=POST_FORM_ACTION_URI?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<input type="hidden" name="WEB_FORM_ID" value="<?=$arParams["WEB_FORM_ID"]?>">
<?=bitrix_sessid_post()?>
```

И шаблон готов.

Comment: Добрый вечер! Спасибо за ответ, но проблему так и не решил. Нажимаю редактировать пшаблон компонента смотрю (соответственно в свой шаблон скопировал). И вижу два подключения 1. bitrix.form и bitrix.form.result.new во втором нахожу ту строчку про котору говорили вы, но при удалении, изменении чего либо в этом файле, ничего не меняется на сайте.... Как буд то это не тот файл

Answer (score 1):

К коментарию на 1 ответ: Возможно, у вас в настройках формы в админке задан шаблон, посмотрите. А еще у компонента есть параметр - игнорировать этот шаблон

Comment: Да, именно так и было :) Я разобрался раньше, но спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в CSS-файле форму как

```
form[name="contact_form"]{}
```

это проще, чем шаблон формы править.

Answer (score 0):

А я всегда делал вот так

```
$arResult["FORM_HEADER"] = substr_replace($arResult["FORM_HEADER"], ' class="contact-form" novalidate="novalidate" ', 5, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Обернуть форму дивом. Ему присвоить класс, например "formclass". В файле стилей прописать .formclass>form{}